# R function to calculate percentage in a new column

Tags: r

```
University  Result  Student_Count   Percentage
A            Pass        30           60.00%
A            Fail        20           40.00%
B            Pass        50           62.50%
B            Fail        10           12.50%
B          No Result     20           25.00%
C            Pass        40          100.00%
```

In this data set compute the percentage column for each university for each result

Comment: Please format your data. And describe what you have tried, always good to show some effort.

Comment: It appears as though you have the percentage column for each university for each result already?

Comment: `df$Percentage <- ave(df$Student_Count, df$University, FUN = prop.table) * 100`

Comment: This is really helpful. I was making a mistake by taking df$Student_Count alone, which was giving me % based on total of student_count irrespective of University. How can I show the complete table along with the plot? I am using ggplot(df,aes(x=University,y= Percentage,fill=Status)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") to plot the stacked barplot. Along the barplot I need to show the raw data(df) as well

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Percentage := paste0(round(100*Student_Count/sum(Student_Count), 2), "%"),
                   by =  University]
```